# Spring Boot Cassandra InvalidQueryException

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I'm building a Springboot Backend using Cassandra as a database stored in Azure.
I'm facing a weird issue which happens randomly, and usually at the first start of the application.

My data model :

```
@Table("product_user_habit")
public class ProductUserHabitDTO {

    @Column
    @PrimaryKey
    private ProductUserKey puk;
    @Column
    private String product_name;
    @Column
    private String category;
    @Column
    private int quantity;
    @Column
    private String brand;

    public ProductUserHabitDTO() {
    }

    public ProductUserHabitDTO(ProductUserKey puk,
                               String product_name,
                               String category, String brand, int quantity) {
        this.puk = puk;
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.category = category;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.brand = brand;
    }
```

My Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface ProductUserHabitsRepository extends CassandraRepository<ProductUserHabitDTO, ProductUserKey> {
    @AllowFiltering
    ProductUserHabitDTO findProductUserHabitDTOByPuk_UseridAndPuk_Code(String username, String code);
}
```

When I call this method, it throws this (usually at first starts) :

```
"Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM product_user_habit WHERE userid='bbbbbbbb' AND code='3274080005003' ALLOW FILTERING;]; Expected size of integer 8: Got 13 bytes; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected size of integer 8: Got 13 bytes","trace":"org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraInvalidQueryException: Query; CQL [SELECT * FROM product_user_habit WHERE userid='bbbbbbbb' AND code='3274080005003' ALLOW FILTERING;]; Expected size of integer 8: Got 13 bytes;"
```

And sometimes it works fine. I don't understand because I don't have any integer in my query. Also for my tests I always use the same query so the userid and code work.

Do someone has a clue of what is happening ? It's driving me crazy :(

Thanks !

Comment: I'm confused. How does this query work at all? You're filtering for userid and code, neither of which I see in your table.

Comment: Userid and code are in ProductUserKey puk, that’s why I specify Puk_* in the name method. Spring Cassandra will convert it to CQL but I don’t understand why it talks about integer size, and why it works almost all the time but get sometimes this error.

Comment: ah got it. strange error though. Have you tried another driver to see if this is isolated to the driver itself?

Comment: btw, I should point out. We don't officially support this driver. See the list here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support

Comment: Oh nice thank you I didn't now that. I was using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra. Will try with one in the link.

Comment: you bet. Will make this answer. Please mark as answer if you could so people can find it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This driver is not officially supported for Cosmos DB's Cassandra API. See the full list of supported drivers here, [Apache Cassandra features supported by Azure Cosmos DB Cassandra API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support).

Thanks.